# Format Timestamp Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column where the record is in the timestamp format **2023-07-03T07:21:31.266-0400**. How can I format this value to **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXREPLACE:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"T|\..+"," ")
```

It replaces the T and everything after the dot. Also you can wrap it in VALUE and format that cell as a date if you need to operate with it